# How do I translate to English?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 8 multilingual site (Spanish [default], English, Italian and Ukranian).

> [image]

On admin/config/regional/translate I can translate to Spanish, Italian and Ukranian but not to English.

> [image]

How can I translate strings to English with this UI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, if you have English configured, it is not available as a translation target. However, you are only one checkbox away from enabling that feature:

[image]

Go edit English and make it available for translation. This will make English behave as any other language and from then on, you can "translate" to English as well:

[image]

All strings will still fall back on the built-in English text (eg. if you also have Hungarian on the site, untranslated strings in Hungarian will fall back on Drupal built-in English text). However when English is used for display, all your overrides will be effective. (Cross-language fallbacks can be implemented in contributed modules now with Drupal 8's service architecture for string lookups).

Source: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2013-aug-20/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-12-english-can-now-be-translated

Result:
[image]

Comment: Would this be good for a monolingual site if there's a desire to change some of the wording used in contrib or core modules?